# how to post the session data into model to insert into db in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**controller**

```
public function respondent_info()
    {    
        $data['states'] = $this->survey_model->get_states();
        $state = $this->session->store['loginData']['state'];
        $financial_year =  $this->session->store['loginData']['financial_year'];
        $getData = $this->survey_model->get_page($state, $financial_year);
        if ($getData == '1') {
            $data['res_info'] = $this->survey_model->get_resinfo_details($state);
            $this->load->view('edit_respondent_info', $data);    
        }else {
            $this->load->view('respondent_info', $data);
        }
        if(isset($_POST['submit_x'])) {
            $respondentArray = array(
                'state' => empty($_POST['state']) ? '' : $_POST['state'],
                'name' => empty($_POST['name']) ? '' : $_POST['name'],
                'title1' => empty($_POST['title1']) ? '' : $_POST['title1'],
                'dline' => empty($_POST['dline']) ? '' : $_POST['dline'],
                'email' => empty($_POST['email']) ? '' : $_POST['email'],
                'organization' =>empty( $_POST['organization']) ? '' : $_POST['organization'],
                'address' => empty($_POST['address']) ? '' : $_POST['address'],
                'city' => empty($_POST['city']) ? '' : $_POST['city'],
                'state1' =>empty( $_POST['state1']) ? '' : $_POST['state1'],
                'zip' => empty($_POST['zip']) ? '' : $_POST['zip'],
                'phone' => empty($_POST['phone']) ? '' : $_POST['phone'],
                'fax' =>empty( $_POST['fax']) ? '' : $_POST['fax'],
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata('respondent_info',$respondentArray);
            $this->survey_model->auto_save_respondent_info( $_POST);
            redirect('survey/budget_overview');
        }
    }
```

**model**

```
 function auto_save_respondent_info($post){
  echo("auto");
  $respondentArray = array(
            'survey_id' => $this->session->store['survey_id'],
            'state' => empty($_POST['state']) ? '' : $_POST['state'],
            'name' => empty($_POST['name']) ? '' : $_POST['name'],
            'title1' => empty($_POST['title1']) ? '' : $_POST['title1'],
            'dline' => empty($_POST['dline']) ? '' : $_POST['dline'],
            'email' => empty($_POST['email']) ? '' : $_POST['email'],
            'organization' =>empty( $_POST['organization']) ? '' : $_POST['organization'],
            'address' => empty($_POST['address']) ? '' : $_POST['address'],
            'city' => empty($_POST['city']) ? '' : $_POST['city'],
            'state1' =>empty( $_POST['state1']) ? '' : $_POST['state1'],
            'zip' => empty($_POST['zip']) ? '' : $_POST['zip'],
            'phone' => empty($_POST['phone']) ? '' : $_POST['phone'],
            'fax' =>empty( $_POST['fax']) ? '' : $_POST['fax'],
        );

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('survey_respondent_info');
    $this->db->where('state',  $state);
    $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
        echo("update");
          // $this->db->where('state',  $state);
          // $this->db->update('survey_respondent_info', $resInfoArray);
        }
        else{
        echo("insert");
          // $this->db->insert('survey_respondent_info', $resInfoArray);
        }
  }
```

here it is not calling the model function, am not able to view the data given in echo. How to call it or how to send the data stored in session to model, i know that something missing in my code, can someone help me please. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated as per user need]
First of all you need to validate the user inputs. You can find example [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html). Next you have to load the model before using it. You can load a model from controller like

```
$this->load->model('survey_model');
```

And if validation is  true you can call the save function as below:

```
$this->survey_model->auto_save_respondent_info();
```

You dont have to pass session or post data to your model.

you can simply access the session from model like

```
    function auto_save_respondent_info(){
        $respondent_info = $this->session->userdata('respondent_info');
        print_r($respondent_info);
        ...............
    }
```

You can access the post data from model as

```
   function auto_save_respondent_info(){
        print_r($_POST);
        ...............
    }
```

Since you are using codeignitor you could use `$this->input->post('fieldname')` instead of $_POST. Also you dont have to save the post data to session to pass it model. You can access `$this->input->post('fieldname')` in you model. Also you should validate your form inputs in controller.

Access post data in Model

```
function auto_save_respondent_info(){
      echo $this->input->post('state');
      .......... 

}
```

I hope you get the point.

Comment: sorry it is not printing anything

Comment: i need the values to be stored in session and also to send those to model in order to store in db

Comment: you can access you post data from model as $this->input->post('fieldname'); you can save the data to session as same as you did

Comment: $respondentArray = array(
      'survey_id' => $this->session->store['survey_id'],
    'state' => empty($_POST['state']) ? '' : $_POST['state'],
    'name' => empty($_POST['name']) ? '' : $_POST['name'],
    'title1' => empty($_POST['title1']) ? '' : $_POST['title1'],
    'dline' => empty($_POST['dline']) ? '' : $_POST['dline'],
    'email' => empty($_POST['email']) ? '' : $_POST['email'],
    'organization' =>empty( $_POST['organization']) ? '' : $_POST['organization'],
    'address' => empty($_POST['address']) ? '' : $_POST['address']); can i give like this in model

Comment: yes you can. but i recommend using $this->input->post() instead

Comment: it is not calling that function atleast. can you send me some example code for this please.

Comment: the model function is not getting called from controller

Comment: Do you have the model in your models folder? Also show your complete model code